# How to switch views using UIActionSheet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How to switch views using UIActionSheet when cancel button is pressed ?

xcode 4.3.2

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Done"]) {
        thiredViewController *controller1 = [[thiredViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"thiredViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:controller1 animated:NO];
    }
}
```

this code do nothing, the view didn't change, my friend told me that i can't use this method to change views in the new Xcode , so what should i use ?

Comment: -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Done"]) {
        thiredViewController *controller1 = [[thiredViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"thiredViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:controller1 animated:NO];
    }}

Comment: I added your code to your question and formatted it correctly. If you want to have an answer to your question, please take some time to make it somewhat convenient for the reader, otherwise probably no one will bother.

Answer (score 0):

You should *never* compare the *title* of a button to decide which action to take. What if you decide to change it elsewhere but forget to change your delegate method as well? This will also get messy if you localize your app in multiple languages.

`UIActionSheet` has a convenient `cancelButtonIndex` method that you can use for this:

```
if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex) {
    //do your thing...
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but what about the method i used to switch the view, its correct or not ? because it didn't work with me

Comment: Edit your question with more detail about how it doesn't work and what actually happens.

Comment: nothing happen, the view didn't change, my friend told me that i can't use this code in Xcode 4.3.2